# how to write this sql query with WHERE clause properly?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

what is the right way to write this sql query

```
select * from articles where id = 1;
select * from users where id = user_id in articles table;
```

my question is how to write the second sql statement properly

Comment: Depending what do you expect result to be. Whether just users, or both articles and users corresponding information.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I am unable to understand what you are really looking for. I think you need to inner join two tables. The query below will give you the result by joining both the tables and it will consider USER_ID column in ARTICLES table represents ID column in USERS.

```
SELECT * FROM USERS INNER JOIN ARTICLES ON USERS.ID = ARTICLES.USER_ID WHERE USERS.ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from users where user_id in (select id from articles);
```

With additional filtering inside select from articles for example. Again, depends on the requested result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles 
INNER JOIN users ON articles.id = users.user_id 
WHERE id = '1'
```

Or use it as a sub query

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT ID 
                  FROM articles 
                  WHERE id = '1')
```

Comment: ids are usually numerical, imho it would be better to avoid type conversion here

Comment: Usually yeah but thats why i gave both